# query for selected checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im having two pages search.php and load.php...in search.php i have checkboxes and im using jquery for passing checkboxes to load.php

```
<div class="checkBoxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="art[]" value="1" >Digital Art <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="art[]" value="2" >Traditional Art <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="art[]" value="3">Photography <br />
</div>


<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".btn_advancedsearch").click(function(){
        $('#content').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#content").load("/search/advancedsearch.php?type="+ $("[name='type']:checked").val()+"&category="+$("input[type='checkbox']").val());
        window.scroll(0,0);
    });
});
</script>
```

In load.php im using `$category=$_REQUEST['category'];` and now i want to write query for getting all selected category from checkboxes but i dont know how...i tryed this query but its not working  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM art WHERE categoryID IN (implode(',', $category))";`

Comment: Look like you need to remember action using SESSION, but I don't like this solutions. You can use function to store and restore a data like set/unset function. Can you selected 2-3 checkboxes and show the results on `var_dump($_REQUEST['category'])`?

Comment: always getting string(1) "1"

Comment: If you getting always "1" it likes you are not receiving right data. You should receive array of dumps data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `$("[name='type']:checked").val()` will return you array object and you cannot pass this directly as a query string parameter. Do the following steps
1. Fetch the selected checkbox values and make them comma separated in a variable (with single quote so use can directly use in the query) _eg. '1','2','3'
2. Pass this value via query string
3. Use this value in your select query -- As you're using `in` operator so you can directly feed this value as `select * from table name where col in (valueYouReceived)`

**Code:**
Somewhere in JS -- When you click on the button `$(".btn_advancedsearch").click(function(){`

```
...
...
var selectedValues = "'";
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
  if($(this).prop('checked'))
  {
     selectedValues += $(this).val()+"',";
  }
});
selectedValues = selectedValues.substring(0, selectedValues.length-1);  // To remove last comma (,)
```

*Just "alert()" the value and see what you get `alert(selectedValues)`*

Now Pass this variable as a query parameter

```
$("#content").load("/search/advancedsearch.php?type="+selectedValues+"&category="+$("input[type='checkbox']").val());
```

At the php part get the value as you're getting it

```
$category=$_REQUEST['category'];
```

Use this value in your sql query

```
"SELECT * FROM art WHERE categoryID IN ($category)";
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found solution. I'm not sure for code but you can change and some put this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(":checkbox").bind("click", function(event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var checked = $(this).val();
        $(".btn_advancedsearch").hide();
        $("#content").load('/search/advancedsearch.php?type=' + checked);
        $('#content').fadeIn(1500);
        window.scroll(0,0);
    }
    });
});​
```

Comment: `var checked = $(this).val();` 
This will get the value of first checkbox only.